# Terraform : how to dynamically create microservices with ECS?

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs

I am stuck with terraform. I want to create dynamically ECS services with terraform.
I have a configuration like this :

```
module/cluster/cluster.tf
module/service/service.tf
```

What I want to do is inject the service name from jenkins into the terraform configuration, so if the service doesnt exist, it creates it (update it if it exists)
I tried to set up different backend s3 remote state but I don't manage to build the whole infrastructure in one terraform apple.

Is there any way to specify dynamically the service configuration so its create them on demand ?

Answer (score 0):

terraform supports to use variable `TF_VAR_<variable>` to do on fly change.

```
From environment variables

Terraform will read environment variables in the form of TF_VAR_name to find the value for a variable. For example, the TF_VAR_access_key variable can be set to set the access_key variable.

Note: Environment variables can only populate string-type variables. List and map type variables must be populated via one of the other mechanisms.
```

For example,

```
TF_VAR_environment=development terraform plan
```

https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/variables.html#from-environment-variables